# Unresolved reference to constraintLayout variable in Kotlin code in android app

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/9475-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-complex-layouts) to create an android app with space animation stuff. In the step titled "Transition Manager" you're instructed to add the following code to your MainActivity.kt file:
`

```
constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout) //1
constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main) //2

departButton.setOnClickListener { //3
  //apply the transition
  TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout) //4
  val constraint = if (!isOffscreen) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
  isOffscreen = !isOffscreen
  constraint.applyTo(constraintLayout) //5
}
```

`
When this code is added the variable "constraintLayout" throws up an unresolved reference error

I think constraintLayout is supposed to be pointing to something in the xml and something is failing to make that happen, I just don't know what.

The kotlin code after adding the above block is:
`

```
package com.raywenderlich.android.razegalactic

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.constraint.*
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.transition.TransitionManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.keyframe1.*


/**
 * Main Screen
 */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
  private val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()

  private var isOffscreen = true

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.keyframe1)

    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
      switch1.setText(if (isChecked) R.string.round_trip else R.string.one_way)


    constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout) //1
    constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main) //2

    departButton.setOnClickListener { //3
      //apply the transition
      TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout) //4
      val constraint = if (!isOffscreen) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
      isOffscreen = !isOffscreen
      constraint.applyTo(constraintLayout) //5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

The main xml is as follows:
`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/flightsIcon"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:src="@drawable/rocket_icon"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/roverIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon" />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/spaceStationIcon"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:src="@drawable/space_station_icon"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/flightsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/roverIcon"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:src="@drawable/rover_icon"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/flightsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/flightsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/flightsIcon" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/spaceStationLabel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/space_stations"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spaceStationIcon" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="124dp"
      android:layout_height="98dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingEnd="20dp"
      android:text="@string/dca"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/roverLabel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/rovers"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/roverIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/roverIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/roverIcon" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="124dp"
      android:layout_height="98dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingStart="20dp"
      android:text="@string/mars"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/flightsLabel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/flights"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/flightsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/flightsIcon"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flightsIcon" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/doubleArrowsIcon"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
      android:src="@drawable/double_arrows"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

  <Switch
      android:id="@+id/switch1"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      android:checked="false"
      android:padding="8dp"
      android:switchPadding="24dp"
      android:text="@string/one_way"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      android:padding="8dp"
      android:text="@string/traveller"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/rocketIcon"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:src="@drawable/rocket_icon"
      app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/galaxyIcon"
      app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
      app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/galaxyIcon"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="90dp"
      android:src="@drawable/galaxy"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.495" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/departButton"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/depart"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`
can anyone tell me what I might be missing or how this can be fixed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suppose to reference a `view` from the `xml` before you can use it.

Do this, also if the name of the layout the `MainActivity` is suppose to use is `main.xml`, it should be the one your `setContentView` use not some other layout.

```
lateinit var cosntraintLayout: ConstraintLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main) // <- main.xml
    cosntraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.ConstraintLayout) // <- add this line
  
    ...
    ...
}
```

`switch1` and `departButton` will also throw the same error, but I'll leave it for you to figure it out based on the code I provided.

Comment: Just checked it, sorry still learning the ropes of this site.

Comment: Agree with that answer, note to always add the type inside the <> or It will throw an error